# Selection between textboxes in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have 3 textboxes TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3 and a button, I want to do the following

If I enter a value in TexBox1 and press the button, some text will be set in textbox2 and textbox3; if I enter a value in TextBox2 and press the button, some data will be displayed in TextBox1 and TextBox3.

I have no idea how to make the code check if the textbox1 value is not null and the textbox2 value is null, to execute a certain statement and set a value to Textbox2 and textbox3; and if the value of Textbox2 value is null and the textbox2 value is not null, to excecute a certain statement and set a value to Textbox1 and textbox3

**Update**

My problem is with this code. If the value of the 2 textboxes is empty, I am getting the correct message, when the first textbox is inserted with data and the second one is empty, the returned value in correct, but when I try to enter values in the second textbox, I am getting the catch exception

```
Private Sub Button9_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button9.Click


    Try


        If SQLConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            If (Me.TextBox5.Text.Length = 0 And Me.TextBox6.Text.Length = 0) Then
                MsgBox("Check your input values.")

            ElseIf (Me.TextBox5.Text.Length > 0 And Me.TextBox6.Text.Length = 0) Then
                Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter("select * from university_members, members_car where(university_members.member_id = members_car.member_id) AND car_id = " & TextBox5.Text, SQLConnection)
                Dim mydatatable As New DataTable()
                Dim dataset As New DataSet()
                myAdapter.Fill(mydatatable)


                If (mydatatable.Rows.Count > 0) Then
                    TextBox6.Text = mydatatable.Rows(0).Item("plate_number")
                    TextBox7.Text = mydatatable.Rows(0).Item("first_name")
                    TextBox8.Text = mydatatable.Rows(0).Item("last_name")
                    TextBox9.Text = mydatatable.Rows(0).Item("type")
                    TextBox10.Text = mydatatable.Rows(0).Item("chassis_id")
                    TextBox11.Text = mydatatable.Rows(0).Item("model")
                    TextBox12.Text = mydatatable.Rows(0).Item("color")
                    ComboBox2.SelectedItem = mydatatable.Rows(0).Item("code")


                Else
                    MsgBox("Check Error: ID Not Found! Enter a Valid ID")
                    ComboBox2.ResetText()
                    TextBox5.Text = " "
                    TextBox6.Text = " "
                    TextBox7.Text = " "
                    TextBox8.Text = " "
                    TextBox9.Text = " "
                    TextBox7.ReadOnly = True
                    TextBox8.ReadOnly = True
                    TextBox9.ReadOnly = True
                    TextBox10.Text = " "
                    TextBox11.Text = " "
                    TextBox12.Text = " "
                End If

            ElseIf (Me.TextBox5.Text.Length = 0 And Me.TextBox6.Text.Length > 0) Then
                Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter("select * from university_members, members_car where(university_members.member_id = members_car.member_id) AND first_name = " & TextBox6.Text & "AND code = '" & ComboBox2.SelectedItem & "'", SQLConnection)
                Dim mydatatable As New DataTable()
                Dim dataset As New DataSet()
                myAdapter.Fill(mydatatable)

                If (mydatatable.Rows.Count > 0) Then
                    TextBox5.Text = mydatatable.Rows(0).Item("car_id")
                    TextBox7.Text = mydatatable.Rows(0).Item("first_name")
                    TextBox8.Text = mydatatable.Rows(0).Item("last_name")
                    TextBox9.Text = mydatatable.Rows(0).Item("type")
                    TextBox10.Text = mydatatable.Rows(0).Item("chassis_id")
                    TextBox11.Text = mydatatable.Rows(0).Item("model")
                    TextBox12.Text = mydatatable.Rows(0).Item("color")



                Else
                    MsgBox("Check Error: ID Not Found! Enter a Valid ID")
                    ComboBox2.ResetText()
                    TextBox5.Text = " "
                    TextBox6.Text = " "
                    TextBox7.Text = " "
                    TextBox8.Text = " "
                    TextBox9.Text = " "
                    TextBox7.ReadOnly = True
                    TextBox8.ReadOnly = True
                    TextBox9.ReadOnly = True
                    TextBox10.Text = " "
                    TextBox11.Text = " "
                    TextBox12.Text = " "
                End If


            End If
        Else
            MsgBox("No Record Found.")
        End If



    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Fatal Error.")
        MsgBox("Application will now exit.")
        Application.Exit()

    End Try


End Sub
```

Comment: Try doing it in jquery rather than doing it in .net.

Answer (score 1):

Check the `length` property

```
If Me.txtBox1.Text.Length > 0 then
'value exists in textbox 1 continue...
end if
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I posted the code that I am facing a problem with. When the TextBox5 and TextBox6 are empty the code is working fine, when Textbox5 value is inserted and the TextBox6 is empty, the code still works, when the value of TexBox6 is inserted and the TextBox5 is empty, I am getting the catch exception.